# Execve problems when reading input from pipe

Tags: linux, pipe, execve

I wrote a simple C program to execute another program using execve.

exec.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        char path[128];
        scanf("%s", path);
        char* args[] = {path, NULL};
        char* env[] = {NULL};
        execve(path, args, env);
        printf("error\n");
        return 0;
}
```

I compiled it:

```
gcc exec.c -o exec
```

and after running it and writing "/bin/sh", it succesfully ran the shell and displayed the `$` sign like a normal shell as can be seen in the picture.

[image]

Then I did the following: I created a server using `nc -l 12345` and ran `nc localhost 12345 | ./exec`. It worked, but for some reason I can't understand, the `$` sign was not displayed this time. I couldn't figure out the reason to this. (demonstrating images attached)

[image]  [image]

Now, here is the weirdest thing.
When I try to pass the program path AND more input via the pipe at once it seems like the executed process just ignores the input and closes.
For example:

[image]

But, if I run the following it works exactly the same way it worked when I piped `nc` output: 
[image]

So, to conclude my questions:

1. I don't understand why the executed shell doesn't print the `$` prompt sign when reads input from a pipe instead of stdin.
2. Why won't the executed program read input from the pipe when the input is already there and not waiting? It seems like it works only in the cases where the pipe remains open after the command execution.

Comment: The shell does not display a prompt if the standard input is not a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like AlexP already mentioned, the prompt sign is only displayed, when input comes from a terminal.

The second question was trickier: When you call libc-function `scanf`, its implementation will not only consume `/bin/sh` from the pipe, but also store the next input `ls` its internal buffers. Those internal buffers, will be overwritten by `execve`, so the shell gets nothing.

Here is your script without scanf to verify this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        char path[128];

        read(0, path, 8); // consume `/bin/sh`
        path[7] = '\0';

        char* args[] = {path, NULL};
        char* env[] = {NULL};
        execve(path, args, env);
        printf("error\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Why did the example with `cat` work in the first place?
That's (probably) because of buffering also. Try:

```
(echo /bin/sh; echo ls) | stdbuf -i0 ./exec
```

I recommend [this nice Article about buffering](https://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/) for further reading.